# Create lines between points layer and line layer (but not the nearest)

Tags: qgis, line, expression, polyline-creation, geometry-generator

I'd like to create lines between a point layer and a line layer, but not in shortest line function in geometry generator. I using this command in geometry generator:

```
make_line (
    $geometry, 
    closest_point (
        array_first (
            overlay_nearest (
                'line' , 
                $geometry
            )
        ), 
    $geometry
    )
)
```

And my result is the yellow line. But I would like to create perpendicular line from point layer to line layer with not closest function (red line). Picture below shows what I mean: The connecting line should have a 90° angle on the line.

[image]

It is possible to make this line (red line) in geometry generator?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE ! I can't really understand exactly what you want. Because an angle of 90° is between 3 points, and a line between 2. So yes, your screenshot works visually and it's very explicit, but what the intended result, for example, if your line was shorter or have sort of curve geometry or go in the "South" direction ?

Comment: Do you have some attribute to indicate which point belong to which line segment?

Comment: just for info: you can shorten your expression code by using `shortest_line` (*ref.* : https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#shortest-line)

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Is it even possible to create lines perpendicular to the main line without using the closest point on the line function? Straight line from point to line segment (no attributes - geometrically)

@BERA I have no such attributes

Comment: it's possible and not possible. Imagine a perfectly circular line around your point, where the perpendicular line should go ?